# show image preview when mouseover on image in table td

Tags: jquery

I'm creating table dynamically using jquery. I put an image in the table's last cell and I want to show image preview when mouseover on   this image in last cell. There is one more condition, I'm taking file path and file type from database so if the file type is not image, I don't want to show image preview. I wrote this codes for this but there is some mistake I guess because it shows image preview every file type.

```
<script>
if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#example' )){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
}
function getData(){

    $('#example tbody').html('');
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO_copy:";
    var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName_copy:";
    var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType_copy:";
    var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
    var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
    var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
    var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'json.wrf',
        type :'get',
        cache :false,
        success: function(data){
            var docs=data.response.docs;
            var html='';        
            $.each(docs,function(key,value){
                var arrayExtensions=["jpg","JPG","JPG File","jpeg","JPEG image","PNG","TIFF image","tiff"];
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center">'+value.PackName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center">'+value.DocType+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center">'+value.DocName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center"><form method="POST" action="openDocumentServlet" target="_blank"><input name="document" value="'+value.FilePath+'" hidden><input name="docName" value="'+value.FileName+'" hidden><input id="buton" type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm" value="OPEN"></form></td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center" id="mouse"><a href="#" class="preview"><img src="images//SoftwareIcons-21-512.png" style="width:50px;height:50px;" id="imageicon"><img id="showImages" src="T:\\Temp\\'+value.FileName+'" class="hide-image"/></a></td>';
                html+='</tr>';
                var n=arrayExtensions.indexOf(value.extType[0]);
                console.log(n);
                if(n>-1){
                    $(document).on("mouseover", ".preview", function() {
                          $(this).find("#showImages").fadeIn();
                    });

                    $(document).on("mouseout", ".preview", function() {
                          $(this).find("#showImages").fadeOut();
                    });
                }
                else{
                    console.log("file not image");
                    $(this).find("#showImages").fadeOut();
                }


            });

            $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
            $('#example tbody').html(html);
            var table=$('#example').DataTable({
                "aaSorting" : [],

            });
        },
    });


};
</script>
```

Comment: What's the value of `value.extType[0]`?

Comment: @iArcadia It comes from database and the value can change every row. The values are like this `pdf`,`jpg`,`png`,`xlsx`...

Comment: I think the issue come from the way you are adding event listeners on your `.preview` elements.

Comment: The way you are currently doing it (`$(document).on("mouseover", ".preview", ...);`), it adds an event on mouse over to **all** your `.preview` elements each time that `n > -1` (= each time your loop meet a image file type).

Comment: @iArcadia Do you have any suggestion to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments:

> I think the issue come from the way you are adding event listeners on your `.preview` elements.
>
> The way you are currently doing it (`$(document).on("mouseover", ".preview", ...);`), it adds an event on mouse over to **all** your `.preview` elements each time that `n > -1` (= *each time your loop meet a image file type*).

I simply suggest your to affect your event listeners directly from the HTML your created in each loop iteration: `$(html).find('.preview').on(...);`.

I made a little snippet that should *simulate* what you have. The (*fake*) AJAX call is made after 2 seconds.

```js
getData();

function getData() {
  $('#example tbody').html('');
  
  /*
   Here your variables.
  */
  
  fakeAjax({
    url: 'your_url',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'json.wrf',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: (data) => {
      const docs = data.response.docs,
        // No need to have the same extensions here even if one is lowercase and not the other.
        imageExts = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'tiff'];
      
      $.each(docs, (key, value) => {
        let html = '', jHtml;
      
        html += '<tr>';
        html += `<td>${value.id}</td>`;
        html += `<td>${value.strSO}</td>`;
        html += `<td class="text-center">${value.PackName}</td>`;
        html += `<td class="text-center">${value.DocType}</td>`;
        html += `<td class="text-center">${value.DocName}</td>`;
        html += '<td class="text-center"><button type="button">OPEN</button></td>';
        // ID must be uniques, so "#showImages" becomes ".showImages" here..
        html += `<td class="text-center"><a class="preview" href="#">[image_here]<div class="showImages">Thumbnail of ${value.FileName}</div></a></td>`;
        html += '</tr>';
        
        jHtml = $(html);
        
        // Adds your HTML before affecting event listeners.
        $('#example tbody').append(jHtml);
        
        if (imageExts.includes(value.extType[0].toLowerCase())) {
          // Finds .preview from the just created HTML.
          jHtml.find('.preview')
            .on('mouseover', function() {
              $(this).find('.showImages').fadeIn();
            })
            .on('mouseout', function() {
              $(this).find('.showImages').fadeOut();
            });
        } else {
          // -----
          // Just for showing that there is no thumbnail.
          jHtml.find('.showImages').addClass('no-thumb').text('NO THUMB SORRY');
          
          jHtml.find('.preview')
            .on('mouseover', function() {
              $(this).find('.showImages').fadeIn();
            })
            .on('mouseout', function() {
              $(this).find('.showImages').fadeOut();
            });
        }
        // -----
      });
    }
  });
}

// Function to simulate the AJAX call. Executes after 2 seconds.
function fakeAjax(options) {
  const data = {
    response: {
      docs: [
        {
          id: 1,
          strSO: 'strSO 1',
          PackName: 'Pack name 1',
          DocType: 'Image file',
          DocName: 'My document',
          FilePath: 'path/to/mydocument.png',
          FileName: 'mydocument.png',
          extType: ['png']
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          strSO: 'strSO 2',
          PackName: 'Pack name 2',
          DocType: 'Text file',
          DocName: 'README',
          FilePath: 'path/to/readme.txt',
          FileName: 'readme.txt',
          extType: ['txt']
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          strSO: 'strSO 3',
          PackName: 'Pack name 3',
          DocType: 'Image file',
          DocName: 'Photography from France',
          FilePath: 'path/to/photofrance.JPG',
          FileName: 'photofrance.JPG',
          extType: ['JPG']
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('AJAX Done. Executing success callback.');
    options.success(data);
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.mouse > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.showImages {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  display: none;
  
  color: #fff;
  
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.showImages.no-thumb {
  color: red;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>strSO</th>
      <th>PackName</th>
      <th>DocType</th>
      <th>DocName</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
      <th>Preview</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's OK. Thanks for helping me to fix it :)